# Why is 1000 rep needed to view vote count?

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges

From https://askubuntu.com/privileges/established-user :

> Voting *scores*, as displayed, are the sum of the up and down votes on a post. Vote counts are the individual up and down votes that make up the score.
>   [image]

Viewing vote counts needs 1000 reputation. Why is this so? Is it sensitive information? Why not display vote counts at reputation 100, or 10, or even 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of the non-essential functionality is withheld from lower-point users to act as an incentive for using the system more. It's essentially an RPG. If you play enough, you get cool little additions.

There were technical arguments against not displaying votes but these have since been resolved.

And as [people discuss here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82442/view-vote-count-privilege-should-be-much-easier-to-gain), there are ways of working out what the breakdown is through the timeline, API or [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I just like to point out that the timeline isn't much helpful to get this data anymore with the new layout. If you are <1k, it only shows a summary of daily scores. For example, if on the same day you get 2 upvotes and 1 downvote, the timeline will only show `daily summary: score: 1`